# ERDAS mosaicPro from 2D view reference layer is not displayed on top

Tags: erdas-imagine, mosaic, landsat-8

I am having an issue using the ERDAS mosaicPro from 2D view tool.  I am using ERDAS 2015.  I have two separate Landsat 8 file bands.  Band 1 from one date and Band 1 from another date.  I have ran the histogram match tool in (Raster \ Radiometric \ Histogram Match).  I want to "stack"/mosaic the two `.tif` files to fill in missing gaps.

Image one shows Band one from December 20th.  The black blobs used to be cloud/shadow coverage.  All black values have been set to "NoData".  Image two shows Band one from April 15th.  Same characteristics as image one.  I have set image one as the reference layer for the mosaic tool, but image 2 is being placed on top in the output.  I tried switching the reference layer, but I get the same result.  I have also tried using the Mosaic to Raster tool in Arcmap 10.4 and get the same result.  Is there something I need to change in the output properties?  Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that the pixel data is the same as the reference layer, it is just that the color is changing.  The process works, just not the color rendering (from what I can tell).